# How to access dynamically created controls in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have dynamically created checkbox's. I have an option "Select All". How do I select all the dynamically created checkboxes in C#?

How to select all the dynamic checkboxes which have been created?

```
protected void chkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkBtn = new CheckBox();
    chkBtn = sender as CheckBox;
    selectedTypeId.Add(Convert.ToInt16(chkBtn.Name));
    foreach(int id in selectedTypeId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you keep the dynamically created checkboxes in a list or array or anything? If not, you can find the controls by name or iterate over the `Controls` property of the form and look for them some other way.

Comment: add each `CheckBox` you create to a `List<CheckBox>` and iterate through the List (un-)checking each one.

Comment: @DrNachtschatten can you give an example?

Comment: @AparajitaSinha posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global List of CheckBoxes:

```
List<CheckBox> boxes;
```

And on your program start instantiate it.

```
boxes = new List<CheckBox>();
```

Each time you dynamically add a CheckBox, also add it to your List.

```
CheckBox chkBtn = new CheckBox();
boxes.Add(chkBtn);
```

When you want to check them all at once, use a loop to go through the list.

```
foreach(CheckBox box in boxes)
    box.Checked = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get all of the CheckBoxes of the control like so:

```
var checkBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
checkBoxes.ToList()?.ForEach(x=>x.Checked = true);
```

But typically you would put all of the checkboxes in groupbox (from ux perspective)

```
groupBox.Controls.Add(checkBox);
```

and then get them from the groupbox:

```
var checkBoxes =  groupBox.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```